# Packaging Laravel, another route is interfering with login route

Tags: laravel-5.4

I'm packaging up a laravel project into separate pieces and though I've created the login/logout routes correctly (I believe), if I don't add a prefix to the route in the service provider, for some reason it tries to use the default controller/routes I created for the landing page of the site. If I change my code to have a prefix, portal for example,it **will** work, but I really just wanted to be able to use the normal /login & /logout paths.

Here are my login routes:

```
Route::get('login',[
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\...\login\LoginController@showLoginForm',
    'as' => 'login'
]);

Route::post('login',[
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\...\login\LoginController@login',
    'as' => 'login.post'
]);

Route::post('logout',[
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\...\login\LoginController@logout',
    'as' => 'logout'
]);
```

Here is my login service provider

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/controllers' => base_path('app/Http/Controllers/.../login'),
        __DIR__.'/views' => base_path('resources/views/vendor/.../auth'),
        __DIR__.'/routes' => base_path('routes/vendor')

    ]);
}

public function register()
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes();
}

protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    $file = base_path('routes/vendor/login-routes.php');
    if(file_exists($file)){
        \Route::group([
            'middleware' => ['web'],
         // 'prefix' => 'portal',
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/vendor/login-routes.php');
        });
    }       
}
```

Here are my landing page/frontend page routes

```
Route::get('/{date?}', [
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\...\frontend\IndexController@loadthis',
    'as' => 'frontend.index'
]);
Route::get('/{date}/reserve/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\...\frontend\ShowReservationController@loadthis',
    'as' => 'frontend.show'
 ]);
Route::post('/{date}/reserve/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\...\frontend\MakeReservationController@loadthis',
    'as' => 'frontend.makeReservation'
]);
Route::get('/{date}/reserve/{id}/delete', [
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\...\frontend\ShowCancelFormController@loadthis',
    'as' => 'frontend.showCancelForm'
]);
Route::delete('/{date}/reserve/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\...\frontend\CancelReservationController@loadthis',
    'as' => 'frontend.cancelReservation'    
]);
```

Here is my landing page/frontend service provider

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([          
        __DIR__.'/views' => base_path('resources/views/vendor/.../frontend/sessions'),
        __DIR__.'/published' => base_path('app/Http/Controllers/.../frontend'),
        __DIR__.'/routes' => base_path('routes/vendor')
    ]);

}

public function register()
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes();
}

protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    \Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['web'],
    ], function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/vendor/frontend-routes.php');
    });
}
```

Let me know if there are any other code pieces you'd need to see. The error I get, which I've tested and know it comes from my frontend index controller function. 
[image]

I've spent so much time on this trying and failing to figure out the cause, I hope you guys can give me some insight on how to solve this, or what's causing this.

**Edit**
Here's a list of my routes
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this package supposed to act as a drop in replacement for authentication purposes? If so, why have the default routes been registered at all, wouldn't that be better handled through your package? And be default I assume you me the standard Laravel Auth routes? Correct me if I'm off base here, but I  just don't see how having default Laravel routes in place would ever play nicely with a package that has conflicting routes.

Comment: Yes, this part of it is. We have a large application and I'm trying to split it apart and package up the different components. So the login/reset password controllers go with my user package. I would like the views I created for that to follow the normal laravel routes of /login rather than making it portal/login. I've taken out all the routes that I initially wrote for the application in the admin.php and web.php route files and separated them into the different packages. I am just unsure at this point why it is trying to use the frontend index controller when the routes stated are different.

Comment: What are the order of your routes as they are are registered with the application? If your landing page/frontend routes come before the  packages login routes, I could see that being a problem, since the Route::get('/{date?}' route will greedily consume matches. At this point I would try testing that theory be reordering your route register, making sure the login related ones get in there early.

Comment: The UserServiceProvider which contains the parts I listed as my login provider is the first thing thats called in my config app.php  "Application Service Providers" section and the first path listed in my composer.json psr-4 section. The frontend one is listed last in each of those parts. That was a good idea though. I'll try the inverse and see if that has any effect, because why not.

Comment: Run php artisan route:list in a terminal and see what order they show up. I'm almost certain this has to simply be the case of a route with very vague matching rules being prioritized too early.

Comment: Edited post to show, thought atm they have portal in front

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, so I awarded you the bounty. I don't know why, but all of the sudden it is working. So maybe something I did the other day fixed it when I tried your suggestions..it didn't seem to at the time, but who knows. It works now, and thanks for the help.

Comment: Much appreciated, glad to hear it is working nonetheless. It almost sounds like a route caching issue if just cleared up. `php artisan route:clear` will force the application to re-evaluate is routes, in case something comes up in the future.

Comment: Good to know, it may have been so.